# BorderColor on XtraUserControl

Tags: c#, user-controls, devexpress, border

Is there a way to add a simple border in a DevExpress `XtraUserControl`?

I tried the following but didn't work:

```
UserDefaultLookAndFeel=False
UseWindowXPTheme = True
BorderColor = Color.Red
BorderStyle = Simple
```

I do not want to add a Docked Panel. This is what I have now but I'm trying to reduce the ammount of controls being user to increase performance.

Comment: The XtraUserControl does not support border colours

Answer (score 0):

*(I'm assuming you are refering to WinForms)*

When I try to add borders to controls that do not support it, I use the following approach:

1. Put a [`Panel` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) on the form.
2. Give the `Panel` a [`Padding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.padding) of 1 on each side.
3. Give the `Panel` a [`BackColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor) of the desired border color.
4. Place your [`XtraUserControl`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsXtraUserControltopic) inside the `Panel` control as a child control.
5. Set the [`Dock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock) of the child control to [`Fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle).

This gives you the look of a 1 pixel thin border in your desired color.

Maybe not the most elegant or resource-saving method, but worked several times for me when nothing else works.

As an additional hint: I have overall extraordinary good experiences with the [DevExpress support website](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/). If my (or the other) answers do not satisfy your needs, I strongly recommend to ask your question again on their support website.

Comment: I am doing this right now, as stated in the question. I was wondered whether I can avoid having a panel.